# Issue in converting O365 user mailbox to shared mailbox with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm working on a script to convert user mailbox to Shared mailbox when the user is terminated.

I'm trying to use the below command

`Get-Mailbox -identity $email | set-mailbox -type "Shared"`

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'type'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I couldn't use the -type parameter for set-mailbox.
can anyone help me fix this issue and please let me know for any questions?

Comment: There answer to your use case is defined/shown in the PowerShell help files for both of those cmdlets. Many articles/blogs/videos cover this as well. What did you search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell version I was using is 4.0 and then I have upgraded it to 5.1, I had an issue in the security protocols of PowerShell v5.1 then when I install ExchangeOnlineManagement Module, everything worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You are piping and email identity, there is no need to explicitly specify it again in the second cmdlet.

> [Understanding the PowerShell Pipeline](https://petri.com/understanding-the-powershell-pipeline#:%7E:text=Understanding%20the%20PowerShell%20Pipeline%201%20Pipeline%20Fundamentals.%20To,need.%203%20A%20Two-Step%20Pipelined%20Expression%20Example.%20)
>
> [Taking the output of a get-mailbox command and piping to a
> set-casmailbox command](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/2dbe9e7e-752a-41a3-bcef-c832bc94aac6/taking-the-output-of-a-getmailbox-command-and-piping-to-a-setcasmailbox-command)

So... this...

```
Get-Mailbox -identity $email | 
Set-Mailbox -Identity $PSItem -Type Shared
```

Many mailboxes, just loop...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I have figured it out, My PowerShell version was 4, and upgraded it to 5.1 and reinstalled the required module then it worked fine.